# How to take time difference in minutes from SQL Server using 24 hour time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 24 h time stored as `last_time` in database and I need to get the difference between current time and `last_time` in minutes. I have searched a lot but in all occasions time difference is taken by by two dates. Please tell me how to use `DiffDate` function correctly using 24 h formatted time.

Comment: you don't care about the date, just time correct? there is no date information, only time correct?

Comment: yes. I am searching only using time because always all the records are in same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time difference is minutes

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, last_time, CAST(getdate() as time)) from <TABLE_NAME>
```

For time difference in DD:MM:SS

```
declare @null time
SET @null = '00:00:00';
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, last_time, CAST(getdate() as time)), @null) from <TABLE_NAME>
```

For MYSQL

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(last_time, cast( now() as time)) as diff
```

Comment: i don' know why but it says that incorrect parameter count in the native function why it is not working datediff @evil333 please help?

Comment: What sql are using? MYSQL , MS SQL, Oracle?

Comment: I am using mysql bro

Comment: Edited to accommodate MYSQL ji

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, last_time, CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108))
```

Comment: i don' know why but it says that incorrect parameter count in the native function why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand too much the question. This query is show difference minutes from last date to current day. Hope it help ?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (minute, last_date, current_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `CAST(GETDATE() AS Time)` for the current time.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Last_Time,CAST(GETDATE() AS Time))
FROM TABLE
```